# Removing Elements and its childrens events

Tags: jquery

I am building a table `tr` dynamically. Each row has a table cell `td` and each cell has a button:

```
var openButton = $('<button class="BtnOpenOrder">Open</button>');
openButton.button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-arrow-1-e" } });
openButton.attr('id', 'btnOpenSession' + i);
openButton.attr('onclick', 'openExistingSession("' + key + '")');
td8.append(openButton); // append to cell
```

In my program I may need to remove all the table rows and create new ones.

```
$("#sessionMenu").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
```

But it seams that removing the rows, doesn't remove the events. So when the new rows are created, an identical event is created. When the event is fired, it fires numerous times. For example, if the rows where deleted and recreated 5 times, when the event is fired, its triggers 5 times. From what I have read, I need to remove the event.

```
 $(".BtnEditOrder").add("*").off();
```

But this seams cause my whole page to refresh when called. Whats the best what to remove the table row and all its events?

**Edit**

Here is a working example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/knj07ya2/)

Comment: Removing the row should remove any bindings that were attached to it.  How are you doing the binding?

Comment: openButton.attr('onclick', 'openExistingSession("' + key + '")');

Comment: Please put the logic in your question.  It's unclear how your doing your binding, if it is in any sort of loop, and what your binding on.  Also, don't bind with onclick.  Attach your event handling with on().  off() only affects event handling attached with on().  attributes on html elements that do bindings are outside the scope of jquery.

Comment: We need to see how you're actually setting up the original event handlers in order to understand what is happening.  Delegated event handlers are attached to a parent object and would survive deleting and recreation of child elements.  Direct event handlers on the actual DOM element would die when the element itself is removed.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited the OP

Comment: Can you create a working example of the issue?  From what you've included it should not be the case that the event is firing multiple times.

Comment: Let me try. If you're saying the multiple firing of events shouldnt happen, then I suspect, my issue is somewhere else in my code.

Comment: @Taplar I edited the OP with a jsfiddle working example. I think the issue is with Firefox as the events fire only once in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There it is!

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnOpenSession' + i, function(e) {
```

Your doing a delegate binding dude.  Don't do that, or only do it once.  That is attaching an event handler to the document that listens for bubbled click events and checks to see if their id matches.  If it does, it processes the handler against them.  Doing that multiple times will make it fire multiple times.

Only do that once, or change it to attach the handler directly to the elements.

**EDIT:**

Also for future reference, if your going to use delegate bindings like this, good practice is to bind as low as possible.  While the logic will only actually execute on the matching elements, the process is still evaluating every event that bubbles up to it to see if it should process.  Meanwhile, such as this case, your really only concerned about events originating from your table.  So it's better to bind on the table.